# load csv file from cloud storage to big query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to load a simple cvs file in Cloud Storage to a BigQuery table using apps script. I have already created the table and want to append the file to existing data in the table. When I run the script I get the following error message 'The mediaData parameter only supports Blob types for upload'. I'm not sure how to progress with this and have hit a brick wall searching for answers. Here is the code snippet I'm using:

```
function loadCloudStorageFileToBigQuery(source, datasetId, tableId, schema) {  
    try{
        var tableReference = BigQuery.newTableReference();
        tableReference.setProjectId(MY_PROJECT);
        tableReference.setDatasetId(datasetId);
        tableReference.setTableId(tableId);

        var load = BigQuery.newJobConfigurationLoad();
        load.setDestinationTable(tableReference);
        load.setSourceUris([source]);
        load.setSourceFormat('CSV');
        load.setSchema(schema);
        load.setMaxBadRecords(0);
        load.setWriteDisposition('WRITE_TRUNCATE');

        var configuration = BigQuery.newJobConfiguration();
        configuration.setLoad(load);

        var newJob = BigQuery.newJob();
        newJob.setConfiguration(configuration);

        var job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(newJob, null, {projectId:MY_PROJECT});

    }catch(err){ 
        Logger.log('Table upload error: %s', err);  
    } 
}
```

Any advice or help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by simply changing the actual load insert to the following:

var job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(newJob, MY_PROJECT);

I also removed the schema as the table already exists

The working function is as follows:

```
        var tableReference = BigQuery.newTableReference();
        tableReference.setProjectId(MY_PROJECT);
        tableReference.setDatasetId(datasetId);
        tableReference.setTableId(tableId);

        var load = BigQuery.newJobConfigurationLoad();
        load.setDestinationTable(tableReference);
        load.setSourceUris([source]);
        load.setSourceFormat('CSV');
        load.setMaxBadRecords(0);
        load.setWriteDisposition('WRITE_APPEND');

        var configuration = BigQuery.newJobConfiguration();
        configuration.setLoad(load);

        var newJob = BigQuery.newJob();
        newJob.setConfiguration(configuration);

        var job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(newJob, MY_PROJECT);
```